# FindControl Inside Gridview CancelEdit Event

Tags: asp.net

Is there is any way to findcontrol hiddenfield inside gridview cancel edit event.
I already tried some methodes,but doesn't work

```
protected void InnerGrid_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
 {
     InnerGrid.EditIndex = -1;
     HiddenField hdCaID = InnerGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hdCaID") as HiddenField;
 }
```

This is my code,but i cant find hiddenfield and i got null exception error.Any Help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `Cell` where you're trying to find the hidden field:

```
int i = e.RowIndex;
HiddenField hdCaID = InnerGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("hdCaID") as HiddenField;
```

**Here is a complete example, code behind:**

```
public partial class GridViewCancel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        var c1 = new Customer { HiddenID = 11, FirstName = "Name1", LastName = "Surname1" };
        var c2 = new Customer { HiddenID = 22, FirstName = "Name2", LastName = "Surname2" };
        var c3 = new Customer { HiddenID = 33, FirstName = "Name3", LastName = "Surname3" };

        InnerGrid.DataSource = new List<Customer> { c1, c2, c3 };
        InnerGrid.DataBind();
    }

    protected void InnerGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        InnerGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
    }

    protected void InnerGrid_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = e.RowIndex;
        HiddenField hdCaID = InnerGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("hdCaID") as HiddenField;
        if (hdCaID != null)
        {
            string value = hdCaID.Value;
        }

        InnerGrid.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="InnerGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCancelingEdit="InnerGrid_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="InnerGrid_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdCaID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("HiddenID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```